# Why same sets giving different outcomes, one is being iterated while another is being printed as whole

Tags: python-3.x, set

Why same sets giving different outcomes, one is being iterated while another is being printed as whole:

```py
my_set1 = {"hello"}
my_set2 = set("hello")
print(my_set1)
print(my_set2)
```

Output:

```py
{'hello'}
{'o', 'l', 'h', 'e'}
```

Exit code: 0

Comment: both are totally different things. one is the set holding only the `hello` and the other is the set of characters `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) takes an iterable as its argument. Strings are iterable. So it iterates over the characters in the `"hello"`.

To achieve the output `{'hello'}` you can call `set(["hello"])`.